# UIViewController and Orientation am I heading in the right direction?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have spent the last several hours trying to get this to work and I can't so I need to know if what I am trying to do is the correct thing.  Its driving me mad!

My goal is to have a ViewController that detects orientation change.  When it's portrait it shows a view with a UITableView, when its landscape it shows a UIView with content that I will programmatically create.

In my parent viewcontroller I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

TableDataViewController *tableDataController = [[TableDataViewController alloc]  
          initWithNibName:@"TableDataViewController"                                                                                
                   bundle:nil];
self.tableDataViewController = tableDataController;
[self.view insertSubview: tableDataController.view atIndex:0];
[tableDataController release];
}
```

This loads my view containing the table view and the controller that goes with it.  The user then rotates the device and the function:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toOrientation                                                 
duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
if (toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    NSLog(@"PerformAnalysisViewController: Gone to Potrait");   
} 

if ((toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || 
    (toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
    NSLog(@"PerformAnalysisViewController: Gone to Landscape");

           // Load new view here
           CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
       UIView *horizView = [[[HorizView alloc]
                  initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
       [self setView:horizView];;   
}
}
```

will trigger depending. However it doesn't trigger? Is this because control has passed to the Subview I have inserted in the viewDidLoad?  If so how do I get it back? Do I have to get it to detect orientation and then remove itself from the superview?

If that was then working would the new view be added as I have it above? I have tried reading the Apple documentation but I can't make this work.

All help greatly appreciated.

Mike

Comment: Did you implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation by returning YES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method in order to handle UI rotation:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
   if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
       interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ) {
      self.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"vertical.png"];
   }
   else {
      self.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"horizontal.png"];
   }

}
```

Please check, that your Info.plist supports more than one orientation and that you have implemented shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation by returning YES.

Comment: It appears it is not triggering - despite setting the info.pist and returning yes in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation

Comment: Ok, I solved it myself.  I deleted the class files and started again I must of corrupted it somehow.